# Oracle Database for SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

Need some help with choosing the correct database version to use several applications like SQL Developer in conjunction with the db. Yesterday I installed Oracle 18C, which when operating consumes around 3-4 gigs of my ram, what's idle version of Oracle DB to run SQL Developer, Jaspersoft's iReport etc. Below I'll attach the specifications of my laptop.

Processor: i3 6100u
Memory: 8 Gigs of DDR3 Memory
Storage: 1TB 5400 RPM HDD
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro (64-Bit)

Currently using 18.4.0-376.1900 (64 Bit version), it would be awesome if you guys could suggest a DB which will be compatible with this version and also should support things like SQLPlus, Jaspersoft's iReport,PL-SQL etc. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Oracle isn't a light database. If you need it, you need resources to run it.

Comment: I just want to know what's the lightest out of the DB which can support SQL Developer and above mentioned applications.

Comment: Grab this, will run ok with 2gb ram for the VM https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest **Oracle 11g Express Edition (XE)** as you're on Windows; there's 18cXE, but only for Linux. Here's the link: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/xe-prior-releases-5172097.html

It is a fully functional, free to use database. True, it has some limitations, but you shouldn't worry about these for what you need. SQL Developer works with it, you can connect other tools to it, it has Oracle Application Express (Apex) installed (version 4.x, but you can upgrade it to the most recent version) ...

Shortly, that's an option you should think about.